How to redirect to a specified route in Nuxt server api?
I am currently doing a project using Nuxt and I am using the Nuxt server/api folder for all of my external API. What I'm trying to do is that, I want to redirect back to the / page if there are any API that return error Unauthorized: Invalid or expired token. I am using axios interceptors for this and able to console out when any API return that error. Just that I am unable to redirect to / page because if I use something like useRouter().push('/');  or redirect('/'), my project console will return error Vue app aliases are not allowed in server runtime.
How can I solve this or is there any other workaround?
My code is as below;
-- server/api/apiService.ts
import axios from 'axios';
import packageJson from '~/package.json';
import { useRouter } from 'nuxt/app';

const config = useRuntimeConfig();

// ---------- dynamic 
interface EnvironmentConfigs {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const environmentConfigs: EnvironmentConfigs = {
    development: config.developmentBaseurl,
    staging: config.stagingBaseurl,
    production: config.productionBaseurl
};

const baseURL = environmentConfigs[packageJson.environment_config];

if (!baseURL) {
    throw new Error('Invalid environment configuration');
}

export const devApiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL,
})

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

// Add response interceptor to handle token expiration
devApiClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        // Do something with response data
        return response;
    },
    (error) => {
        // Do something with response error
        if (error.response.data === 'Unauthorized: Invalid or expired token\n') {
            console.error('Token expired, redirecting to login page...');
            const router = useRouter();
            router.push('/login');
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

-- server/api/apiEventHandler.ts
import { apiErrorHandler } from './apiErrorHandler';
import packageJson from '~/package.json';

const API_VERSION = packageJson.version;

type AuthType = 'Bearer' | 'Basic';
type DataFormat = 'URLSearchParams' | 'FormData';

export function apiEventHandler(handlerFn: (
    headers: any, params: any, type: any) => Promise<any>,
    authType: AuthType = 'Bearer', // Default to 'Bearer'
    dataFormat: DataFormat = 'URLSearchParams' // Default to URLSearchParams
) {
    return eventHandler(async (event: any) => {
        try {
            let query, token;

            if (dataFormat === 'FormData') {
                query = await readMultipartFormData(event);
                token = query?.find((part: any) => part.name === 'token')?.data.toString();
            } else {
                query = JSON.parse(await readBody(event));
                token = query?.token;
            }
            
            // Initialize headers based on authType
            const headers: any = authType === 'Bearer'
                ? { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }
                : { 'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(`${useRuntimeConfig().ssoUsername}:${useRuntimeConfig().ssoPassword}`)}` };

            // Initialize params based on dataFormat
            const params: any = dataFormat === 'URLSearchParams'
                ? new URLSearchParams()
                : new FormData();

            // const params = new URLSearchParams();
            params.append('version', API_VERSION);
            // Check if query.data exists to handle params construction
            if (query.data) {
                for (const item of query.data) {
                    // Dynamically append parameters based on item keys
                    for (const key in item) {
                        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(item, key)) {
                            params.append(key, item[key]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return await handlerFn(headers, params, query);
        } catch (error: any) {
            return apiErrorHandler(error);
        }
    });
}

-- server/api/apiErrorHandler.ts
export function apiErrorHandler(error: any) {
    // return { error: error.message || 'Unknown error' };

    // Check if the error response is available
    if (error.response) {
        const { data } = error.response;

        // Check if there is a specific error message
        if (data && typeof data === 'string') {
            return { error: data };
        }

        // Fallback, return the error response to the client
        return {
            // error: data.error.details.reason || data.error || 'An error occurred while processing the request'
            error: data.error || 'An error occurred while processing the request'
        };
    } else {
        // If no error response, return a generic error message
        return {
            error: error.message || 'An internal server error occurred'
        };
    }
}

-- server/api/apiEndpoints.ts
// list of API Endpoints

export const API_ENDPOINT = {
    LOGIN: 'EXTERNAL_API_ENDPOINT_HERE'
};

-- composables/useApiPath.ts
export const useApiPaths = () => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig();
    const baseURL = config.app.baseURL;
    
    const apiPaths = {
        apiLogin: `${baseURL}api/auth/apiLogin`
};

    // console.log('Config:', config);
    // console.log('API Paths:', apiPaths);
    return apiPaths;
};

-- server/api/auth/apiLogin.ts
import { devApiClient } from '../apiService'
import { API_ENDPOINT } from '../apiEndpoints';
import { apiEventHandler } from '../apiEventHandler';

const handlerFn = async (headers: any, params: any) => {
    // Add specific headers for this API call
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    
    try {
        const response = await devApiClient.post(API_ENDPOINT.LOGIN, params, { headers });
        const responseData = response.data;

        if (responseData.success) {
            return responseData.data;
        }

        throw new Error('API returned error: ' + responseData.message);
    } catch (error: any) {
        throw error; // Allow the global error handler to handle this
    }
}

export default apiEventHandler(handlerFn);

How I call the API in pages :
const getLogin = async () => {
    const dataArray = [{ contact: emailField, code: passwordField }];

    const response = await fetch(useApiPaths().apiLogin, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            token: authStore.sso_token, data: dataArray
        }),
    });
    const responseData = await response.json();
}

What I've Tried

Using useRouter().push('/')
Using redirect('/')

Both approaches result in the same error.
When I use useRouter().push('/') within the Axios interceptor, I get the error Vue app aliases are not allowed in server runtime.
How can I properly redirect to / on receiving Unauthorized: Invalid or expired token error in the Axios interceptor? Is there a workaround or another approach I should consider?

TLDR;
You cannot use anything specific to Nuxt in server folder. Refer to unjs/nitro documentation. To answer your whery, you should return sendRedirect('/') in your even handler.
If you want to use Axios, wrap around with a promise and resolve or reject that. Then, catch the rejection in eventHandler and return sendRedirect()
Lastly, if you want to live happily in Nuxt ecosystem, use ofetch i.e. $fetch() provided officially by Nuxt.
